# Calculate the ratio between columns based on the condition in R

Tags: r

Hi I am doing a very simple thing here.

I have 3 columns of data; a, b and c. I want to calculate the ratio of b and c when the value of b is only greater than 5.

The code I used is as follows:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
b <- c(2,4,5,8,10,12,15,18)
c <- c (10,9,8,15,31,12,13,12)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
 ## Calculate the ratio 
df$d <- with(df,b/c)
```

I calculated the ratio but couldn't use the condition there. I know its trivial but this is taking a lot of time. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ifelse`. You don't say what you want the result to be in cases where b is less than 5, so I've assumed you want `NA` there.:

```
> df$d <- with(df, ifelse(b > 5, b/c, NA))
> df
  a  b  c         d
1 1  2 10        NA
2 2  4  9        NA
3 3  5  8        NA
4 4  8 15 0.5333333
5 5 10 31 0.3225806
6 6 12 12 1.0000000
7 7 15 13 1.1538462
8 8 18 12 1.5000000
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am also trying to use if else condition but couldn't figure it out. I will mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think that `transform` is more elegant here :) (slightly different of @Ananda solution)

```
 transform(df, d= ifelse(b > 5, b/c, NA))
  a  b  c         d
1 1  2 10        NA
2 2  4  9        NA
3 3  5  8        NA
4 4  8 15 0.5333333
5 5 10 31 0.3225806
6 6 12 12 1.0000000
7 7 15 13 1.1538462
8 8 18 12 1.5000000
```

Comment: +1 for another alternative, and just for fun, if you have a moment, please comment [on this](http://news.mrdwab.com/2012/12/04/what-exactly-is-elegant-code-in-r/).

Comment: @AnandaMahto Sure I will do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can subset values for `df$d` and inside  the `with()` function.

```
df$d[df$b>5] <- with(df[df$b>5,],b/c)
df
  a  b  c         d
1 1  2 10        NA
2 2  4  9        NA
3 3  5  8        NA
4 4  8 15 0.5333333
5 5 10 31 0.3225806
6 6 12 12 1.0000000
7 7 15 13 1.1538462
8 8 18 12 1.5000000
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd first calculate the ratio, and then assign `NA` to the values where `b < 5`:

```
df = within(df, { d = b / c })
df$d[df$b <= 5] <- NA

> df
  a  b  c         d
1 1  2 10        NA
2 2  4  9        NA
3 3  5  8        NA
4 4  8 15 0.5333333
5 5 10 31 0.3225806
6 6 12 12 1.0000000
7 7 15 13 1.1538462
8 8 18 12 1.5000000
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I knew 3 ways to do one thing.